# Как реализовать правильную связь классов в javascript?

Tags: javascript, ооп, полиморфизм

Теперь в деталях : имеются несколько классов :

```js
class RemovedItem {
  constructor(value, key) {
    this.value = value;
    this.key = key;
}
 }
 
 class AddedItem {
  constructor(value, key) {
    this.value = value;
    this.key = key;
}
}
class ChangedItem {
  constructor(beforeValue, afterValue, key) {
    this.afterValue = afterValue;
    this.beforeValue = beforeValue;
    this.key = key;
}
}
```

для каждого из этих классов (их больше чем в примере но не суть) нужно реализовать собственный класс рендерер ( например RemovedRenderer для RemovedItem ) который будет выводить строковое представление итема . Дальше в некую функцию будет передаваться массив этих итемов и внутри нее как то нужно автоматически вызывать для каждого итема свой рендерер. Проверки в стиле

```js
if (item instanceof AddedItem )
```

не в счет ибо такой код убивает идеи ооп .

Comment: Не часто я вижу примеры на javascript с классами, так как в самом по себе языке вся фишка в прототипом наследовании

Comment: Вы правы но в данном случае нужно сделать именно на классах

Comment: Просто добавить в каждый класс метод `render`?

Comment: реализация итемов и рендереров не должна смешиватся , это 2 разных уровня абстракции . Плюс рендереры могут быть разного формата (например RemovedRendererStyle1 и RemovedRendererStyle2 ) так что это не подходит

Comment: @АртёмНегода, вы правы, об этом я не подумал когда писал коммент.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну на ум приходит что то типа такого:

```js
    class ItemType1 {
        constructor() {
            // ...
        }
    }
     
    class ItemType2{
        constructor() {
            // ...
        }
    }
     
    class ItemType3 {
        constructor() {
            // ...
        }
    }
    
    // Объект, содержащий методы для рендеринга определённых типов айтемов. 
    const render = {
        ItemType1(item) {
            console.log(1);
        },
     
        ItemType2(item) {
            console.log(2);
        },
     
        ItemType3(item) {
            console.log(3);
        }
    };
     
    [new ItemType1, new ItemType2, new ItemType3].
        forEach((item) => render[item.constructor.name](item) );
```

Имя метода в объекте `render` должно совпадать с именем класса, который планируется рендерить.

Comment: не плохо спасибо )

Comment: Правда говорят диспетчеризация по типам (это ведь она ? ) и классы совмещать не совсем правильно.

Comment: @АртёмНегода, что вы понимаете под "диспетчеризацией по типам"? В javascript нет возможности перегрузить функцию или метод.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то вам может подойти что-то такое.

```js
class ItemBase {
  render() {
    console.log('ItemBase render');
  }
}

class Item1 extends ItemBase {
  render() {
    super.render();
    console.log('Item1 render');
  }
}

class Item2 extends ItemBase {
  render() {
    console.log('Item2 render');
  }
}

class Item3 extends ItemBase {

}

[new Item1(), new Item2(), new Item3()].forEach(e => e.render())
```

Если вам все же нужен отдельный класс для рендера можно сделать вот так

```js
class BaseRenderer {
  render(item) {
    console.log('BaseRenderer render', item);
  }
}

class Item1Renderer extends BaseRenderer {
  render(item) {
    super.render(item);
    console.log('Item1Renderer render', item);
  }
}

class Item2Renderer extends BaseRenderer {
  render(item) {
    console.log('Item2Renderer render', item);
  }
}

class ItemBase {
  constructor(renderer) {
    this._renderer = renderer;
  }
  render() {
    this._renderer.render(this);
  }
}


class Item1 extends ItemBase {

}

class Item2 extends ItemBase {

}

class Item3 extends ItemBase {
  constructor() {
    super({
      render: (item) => console.log('sef-made', item)
    });
  }
}


[new Item1(new Item1Renderer()), new Item2(new Item2Renderer()), new Item3()].forEach(e => e.render())
```

Comment: Решил сделать что то среднее между двумя ответами , иерархия классов как в этом примере а для определения правильного рендерера использовать пример выше так как в массиве приходят только итемы (без определения рендерера в конструкторе ).

Comment: @АртёмНегода Посмотрите на второй пример класс `Item3`. Можно в конструкторе рендер не передавать, а создавать его непосредственно в классе.

Comment: проблема в том что итемы вообще не должны ничего знать о рендерерах . Нужно что то похожее только наоборот (рендерер должен принимать итем в конструктор ). И это присваивание должно происходить автоматически после того как массив итемов уже сформирован и пришел в функцию.

Comment: @АртёмНегода поясните, что вы понимаете под *И это присваивание должно происходить автоматически после того как массив итемов уже сформирован и пришел в функцию*. Вы же понимаете, что само собой автоматически ничего подобного происходить не может!

Comment: Посмотрите мой ответ который я добавил . Не нужно в ручную определять нужный рендерер для итема потому что он его наследует . Я хотел это реализовать вообще без никаких связей между этими 2 абстракциями но так тоже сойдет .

Comment: @АртёмНегода Вы же понимаете, что сейчас связали класс рендер с итемом? Более того, в классе рендере вы не сможете использовать свойства\поля из итема. Точнее сможете, но это будет абсолютно не правильно с точки зрения ООП.

Comment: да без связей не получилось

Answer (score -1):

Собственно отвечаю на свой вопрос))) :

```js
class Type1Renderer 
{

getStyleOneString () { return `is type1 style1 ${this.value}`}
//добавление новых форматов/стилей происходит посредством добавления функции в класс рендерера
getStyleTwoString () { return `is type2 style2 ${this.value}`}

}

class Type2Renderer 
{
getStyleOneString () { return `type2 style 1 ${this.value}`}

getStyleTwoString () { return `type 2 style2 ${this.value}`}
}



//классу итема достаточно просто наследоватся от нужного рендерера
class ItemType1 extends Type1Renderer
{
constructor(value){
super();
this.value=value;
}
}

class ItemType2 extends Type2Renderer
{
constructor(value){
super();
this.value=value;
}
}

//теперь в функции каждый итем будет вызывать свой getString
console.log([new ItemType1('fiz'),new ItemType2('baz')].map(item => item.getStyleOneString()));
```

Comment: в чем смысл передачи объекта в метод этого же объекта?

Comment: @Grundy , согласен , отредактировал.